# running python script (with GUI wxpython) as a service

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, service, upstart

I have a python script with GUI (using wxpython). I want to run it continuously on my (k)ubuntu system as a service. In case it exits due to some exception, I need it to restart automatically. I tried upstart but it immediately stops the service as soon as it starts.

Is there a super simple way to do this? (I tried restarting the python script within itself, tried simple shell scripts with infinite loops. But need something robust and reliable.)

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: This sounds like more of a Linux system administrator question.  It seems to me like you would be able to get better help by getting rid of the python and wxpython tags and adding linux and Ubuntu tags.

Comment: makes sense! just did that! thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know you said you tried shell scripts with infinite loops, but did you try using an "outer" Python script that runs perpetually as a service; it could just catch the exceptions and restart the Python GUI script if an exception were to occur.

Something like:

```
import myGUI

while True:
  try:
    myGUI.runGUICode() # make sure the execution stays in this loop
  except:
    pass # or do some recovery, initiallization, and logging here
```

Comment: Tried this... but not sure if this is the best way to do it.